# Extracting the source of a Javascript in a page with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, browser

I am trying to find an embedded stream link from [a page](http://myiframe12.altervista.org/channel1.php). When I check for the source code of that page it returns something similar to below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> swidth='640', sheight='460';</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.sawlive.tv/embed/hqfootyerech1'></script>
```

[This](http://www.sawlive.tv/embed/hqfootyerech1) also returns code like:

```
http://sawlive.tv/embed/watch/xxxxxxx_
```

I have tried with `file_get_contents` to crawl to http://www.sawlive.tv/embed/hqfootyerech1 but it does not return anything.

The page only loads from http://myiframe12.altervista.org/

Is there a way to get the full source code of the page including the embedded page and script? I can inspect the elements loaded on that page with Firefox, but the source codes are different.

I have heard of Selenium2. But no idea how it works either.

Comment: I have also tried Curl..

Comment: Not really understanding what you're trying to do. the sawlive.tv url loads some javascript that writes an iframe. How does that relate to the myiframe12 url?

Comment: If the source is generated via javascript probably you should emulate a browser. You can do this with selenium . I have done this in python with spynner check here https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner

Comment: some of the stream links are domain locked..my target page also contains the link that can only be viewed if specific page is loaded..how do I load selenium in my server?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `file_get_content`.
There is a difference if you call it with http or a path to your file.

If you wish to get the source code you should write:

```
file_get_contents('path/to/YOUR/FILE.php');
```

You probably called a file with it's URL which is different, if you use http u can only see the ouput of the PHP script, so use the path.

I don't think you can access the source code of a file not on your domain, but i'm not sure about that.

**EDIT : **

In case this dosen't work, i found this code, not tested but should work too :

```
ob_start();
include "yourfile.php";
$myvar = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: when i use file_get_contents("http://myiframe12.altervista.org/channel1.php") it only returns plain codes but I want to see the source of the embed element code to capture my stream link